# Angular root scope update

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a page with a "status" section for the logged in user where it says "Welcome, [name]", with a "logout" link if they are indeed loggedin.

I'm trying to log them in by setting values on $rootScope from the `LoginController` and want the "status" section to change, but nothing happens. I have the chrome extension installed and I get see that `$rootScope.loggedIn` is indeed set to `true`.

```
angular.module('pipelineChromeApp')
.controller('LoginController', [
'$rootScope',
'$scope',
'Profile',
'$location',
function ($rootScope, $scope, Profile, $location) {
  $scope.apiKey = '';
  $scope.error = '';


  $scope.login = function(){
    $scope.error = '';

    var login = Profile.getProfile($scope.apiKey)

    login.then(function(resp){

      $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
      $rootScope.name = resp.data.first_name;
      $rootScope.apiKey = resp.data.api_key;
      $rootScope.avatar = resp.data.avatar_thumb_url;

      // Sets data in localstorage
      Profile.login(resp.data);

      $location.path( "/actions" );

    }, function(error) {
      $scope.error = error.data.error;

    });
  };
}]);


angular.module('pipelineChromeApp')
.controller('StatusController', [
'$rootScope',
'Profile',
'$scope',
'localStorageService',
function ($rootScope, Profile, $scope, localStorageService) {
  $scope.loggedIn = $rootScope.loggedIn;
  $scope.name = $rootScope.name;

  $scope.logout = function() {
    Profile.logout()
    $location.path("/start");
  };

}]);
```

And the template:

```
<div class="status" ng-controller="StatusController">
  <div ng-if="loggedIn">
    Welcome, <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
    <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have to use $watch in the `$rootScope` to updated the local `$scope`.